# install latest version of R 3.2.1 (World-Famous Astronaut) on Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE)

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, apt, r

I have tried multiple ways (referencing multiple forum posts) to install the latest version of R (3.2.1 "World-Famous Astronaut") on Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE).

I tried different sources lists, the most recent being:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

but when I call:

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base-dev
```

with each of the ones I try, I always get:

```
3.0.2-1ubuntu1
```

as the most recent one available.

Has anyone been able to install 3.2.1 on Linux Mint? Thanks in advance.

- Tom

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the priorities of repositories.

Edit `/etc/apt/preferences` and add

```
Package: *
Pin: origin cran.rstudio.com
Pin-Priority: 900
```

And I would use

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

Jessie and Wheezy are Debian version names.

As Mint 17 derives from Ubuntu 14.04, jessie (Release April 2015, Freeze November 2014) is the more natural source than wheezy (Release May 2013, Freeze June 2012). But thats just a personal opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I have changed my deb as you suggested. Im not sure how to change my priorities though. When I go to /etc/apt/ I have a folder called "preferences.d" that only contains "official-extra-repositories.pref" and "official-package-repositories.pref" files.

Comment: Continuing: from this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository it seems that putting a specific .deb at the top of the source.list will control what version of something is installed. My sources.list currently only has the 'deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/ ' that you suggested (I just did a fresh install of Mint 17.1), so would I even need to change the /etc/apt/preferences? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Thanks for all the help! I will post an answer here for anyone else trying to figure this out:

First I ran:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to get into my `sources.list` file. Then I added:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

and also added the key: (thanks Dirk for the suggestion):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480

sudo apt-get update
```

then when I ran:

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base-dev
```

to see the available packages. The top one was:

```
Package: r-base-dev
Versions: 
3.2.1-1~wheezycran3.0(/var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_debian_wheezy-cran3_Packages)
```

so, finally I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -f r-base=3.2.1-1~wheezycran3.0
```

which worked great!